# Sisense continuous timeline until today(without value from data)

Tags: date, graph, zero, sisense

is there a possiblity to create continuous timeline until today, even if today has no values?
I see in documentation we can fill missing gaps, https://documentation.sisense.com/7-1/creating-dashboards/additional-widget-designs/create-continuous-chart.htm#gsc.tab=0
but if there are no values, lets say last 3 days, there is nothing showed on the graph.
I would need to see the zeros also until the last day, not only for zero values between.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The documentation you linked is for v 7.1 which is quite old.  Below is a similar topic for the latest version, but make sure you're looking at documentation for a version that is at least close to what you're running.  If you're really on v 7.1, upgrading would be highly recommended.

https://documentation.sisense.com/latest/managing-data/working-with-data/handlenull.htm#gsc.tab=0

This may be something to report to Sisense, it seems like the 'show null as zero' feature would do exactly what you want it to.

A workaround could be to change the nulls to 0 in the data model. Implement this as a custom column if preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: Create a date dimension table that has all the dates and left join your data to this (matching date to date).

That way you won't have any gaps in days, and have 0s for the days where there are no entries.

This article from Sisense talks about when date dimension tables are useful (the example you provided with non-consecutive data but wanting to graph consecutively) and provides and excel file you can upload to create your date dim table.

https://support.sisense.com/kb/en/article/date-dimension-file